# React Native checkbox showing up as red dot

Tags: ios, checkbox, react-native, react-native-ios

The react native checkbox is showing fine in android but in ios its showing as a little red dot. Does the checkbox work in ios or just android?

```
<CheckBox
  label='I accept the Terms and Conditions'
  value={this.state.checked}
  onValueChange={() => this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CheckBox` component, provided by `react-native`, only works on Android as it quite clearly states the following in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/checkbox.html)

> Renders a boolean input (Android only).

Also it does not have a `label` prop.

Its listed props are:

- [View props..](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#props)
- `disabled`
- `onChange`
- `onValueChange`
- `testID`
- `value`

Comment: Thank you some how missed this.